# How can I calculate the acutal elapsed time in my timezone between two dates in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone, datetimeoffset

How do I calculate the **actual elapsed** time between two `DateTime`/`DateTimeOffset`, both in my timezone, taking daylight saving time, leap years, etc, into account?

For example, the following code comparing the difference between 00:00 and 05:00 of March 29th 2020 will output a timespan of 6 hours (05:00 becomes 06:00 after the conversion to local time, since daylight saving time starts 02:00 in my timezone, changing clocks forward from 02:00 to 03:00).

```cs
var timezone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;

var start = new DateTimeOffset(2020, 03, 29, 00, 00, 00, timezone.BaseUtcOffset).LocalDateTime;
var end   = new DateTimeOffset(2020, 03, 29, 05, 00, 00, timezone.BaseUtcOffset).LocalDateTime;

var diff1 = end.Subtract(start);
var diff2 = end - start;

Console.WriteLine(diff1); // 06:00:00
Console.WriteLine(diff2); // 06:00:00
```

I'm trying to get an output of **4 hours** in the example above since that is the elapsed time between 00:00 and 05:00.

```
00:00 -> 01:00 (+ 1 hr)
01:00 -> 02:00 (+ 1 hr)
02:00 -> 03:00 (0)
03:00 -> 04:00 (+ 1 hr)
04:00 -> 05:00 (+ 1 hr)

= 4 hrs
```

I'm clearly missing something here. I've read [Comparisons and arithmetic operations with DateTimeOffset values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/performing-arithmetic-operations#comparisons-and-arithmetic-operations-with-datetimeoffset-values) but can't wrap my head around how to do this calculation.

I am aware that NodaTime can probably achieve this, but surely there's a way to do this without external libraries?

Comment: The elapsed time is 5 full hours, not 4. Assuming DST rules didn't come into force on that date, in which case `end`'s offset would be wrong. Using an offset isn't enough to handle DST, you need to know the actual timezone. The de-facto standard for timezone calculations is the IANA timezone database, used by almost everyone except Windows. You can use it in .NET through the NodaTime library

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It says in the question that DST changed on that date, or what do you mean? If I had a stopwatch on this date, started it 00:00 and stopped it 05:00, it would show me that 4 hours elapsed.

Comment: So the offset is wrong. It's no longer the `BaseUtcOffset`, it's a different one.  `LocalDateTime` doesn't perform any DST conversions, it returns a `DateTime` based on the offset stored in DateTimeOffset. You could have calculated the differenc simply by subtracting the two `DateTimeOffset` values, you don't gain anything by going through `LocalDateTime`

Comment: To get the correct DateTimeOffset you can use [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime,TimeZoneInfo)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime?view=netcore-3.1) to convert a local DateTime to a DateTimeInfo using the offset specified by that timezone's DST rules. I always prefer to use NodaTime with explicit timezone names though. All commercial web services report times using the IANA timezone names, eg `Europe/Berlin` or `Europe/Athens`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If you remove LocalDateTime both diffs become 5 hours, so it clearly does some DST conversions. However, I appreciate the fact that you pointed out the UTC offset, I believe I've figured out how to get the elapsed time. Will post answer.

Comment: I would naively think the best thing to do is to convert locale driven datetimes into the UTC timestamps for start/end and then find the difference of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62679509/634824) is fine, and is the correct approach when the offset is not provided with if the time zone, assuming it can be any arbitrary time zone.

However, if you are *only* working with the *local* system time zone, you can simplify the code as follows:

```
var start = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2020, 3, 29, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local));
var end   = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2020, 3, 29, 5, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local));
TimeSpan diff = end - start;
```

This works because the `.Kind` property of a `DateTime` is evaluated when passed into the `DateTimeOffset` constructor that takes a single `DateTime` parameter.  If it's `DateTimeKind.Local` or `DateTimeKind.Utc`, then the offset is set correctly.  It's only in the case of `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` that the offset could be incorrect (because it will assume local, even if that's not the case).  [See the remarks in the docs here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.-ctor#System_DateTimeOffset__ctor_System_DateTime_)

Answer (score 2):

As [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) pointed out,

> So the offset is wrong. It's no longer the BaseUtcOffset, it's a different one

I found [TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.getutcoffset?view=netcore-3.1) and used that. I think it does what I want? Timezones are confusing, but at least I get my output of 4 hours now.

```cs
var timezone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;

var startTime = new DateTime(2020, 03, 29, 00, 00, 00);
var endTime   = new DateTime(2020, 03, 29, 05, 00, 00);

var startTimeOffset = timezone.GetUtcOffset(startTime);
var endTimeOffset   = timezone.GetUtcOffset(endTime);

var start = new DateTimeOffset(2020, 03, 29, 00, 00, 00, startTimeOffset);
var end   = new DateTimeOffset(2020, 03, 29, 05, 00, 00, endTimeOffset);

var diff1 = end.Subtract(start);
var diff2 = end - start;

Console.WriteLine(diff1); // 04:00:00
Console.WriteLine(diff2); // 04:00:00
```

Comment: Have you tried `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime()` ? Eg `var start=TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(startTime,timezone)` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That seems to still give me a diff of 5 hours.
`startTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(startTime, timezone);`

Comment: This answer is fine, but a couple of things to point out.  1) There is a `DateTimeOffset` constructor that accepts a `DateTime` and a `TimeSpan`, so you could just pass the `startTime` and `endTime` into the constructor instead of specifying the integers twice.  2) For `GetUtcOffset` (and really any case where an offset is determined, such as in my answer below also), be aware that in the case of ambiguous or invalid local time (such as occur with DST transitions), .NET will assume you want the *standard* time offset, even if you may have in fact wanted the *daylight* time offset.